# Stored procedure SQL Server. Income payment query

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple task but i can't figure it out. Just need to write query where incoming payment will "pay" existing debts in the table.

What i got:

```
Date            Amount  Amount_Rest
2018-12-05  150,00  150,00
2018-12-05  150,00  150,00
2018-12-08  100,00  100,00
2018-12-08  100,00  100,00
2018-12-11  170,00  170,00
2018-12-11  170,00  170,00
2018-12-14  105,00  105,00
2018-12-14  105,00  105,00
2018-12-16  45,00   45,00
```

And after we have payment i.e. '250,00' , we will update data in table like here
What i want to get:

```
Date            Amount  Amount_Rest
2018-12-05    0,00    0,00
2018-12-05    0,00   50,00
2018-12-08  100,00  100,00
2018-12-08  100,00  100,00
2018-12-11  170,00  170,00
2018-12-11  170,00  170,00
2018-12-14  105,00  105,00
2018-12-14  105,00  105,00
2018-12-16  45,00   45,00
```

What i try:

```
DECLARE 
     @D_Date    date 
    ,@N_amount  money

DECLARE 
    cursor_pay CURSOR 
FOR SELECT
     D_Date
    ,N_Amount
FROM 
    dbo.FD_Bills

OPEN cursor_pay

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        PRINT
            CAST(@D_Date AS varchar) +
            CAST(@N_amount AS varchar);
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pay INTO
             @D_Date
            ,@N_amount
    END;

CLOSE cursor_pay;
DEALLOCATE cursor_pay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cursor or loop. Just cumulative sum with case expression

I assumed there is an `ID` column that can uniquely identify the rows. Replace it with your column.

```
declare @payment decimal(10,2) = 200.00;

select *,
       P_Amount = case when @payment >= sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID)
                       then b.R_Amount
                       when @payment >= sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID) - b.R_Amount
                       then @payment -  sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID) + b.R_Amount
                       else 0
                       end
from   dbo.FD_Bills b
order by b.ID;
```

The above query will gives you the payment amount for applied to the transactions in ascending order by date

With that you can update back your table with a update query.

```
update b
set    N_Amount = 0,
       R_Amount = p.P_Amount
from   dbo.FD_Bills b
       inner join
       (
         select ID,
                P_Amount = case when @payment >= sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID)
                                then b.R_Amount
                                when @payment >= sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID) - b.R_Amount
                                then @payment -  sum(b.R_Amount) over (order by D_Date, ID) + b.R_Amount
                                else 0
                                end
         from   dbo.FD_Bills b
       ) p      on b.ID = p.ID
where  p.P_Amount > 0
```